# How to say "local community" in ONE word?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm struggling to say 'local community' in one word. Is there a suitable word which describes 'local community' or synonym?

Comment: *Neighborhood?*

Comment: Localcommunity.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Beat me to it.

Comment: @JohnLawler You win a month of free internet!

Answer (score 3):

Will *neighborhood* work well?

> a district, especially one forming a community within a town or city.
>   [[Google]](http://www.google.com/search?q=neighborhood%20definition)

Answer (score 0):

How about *microcosm* ?

> a community, place, or situation regarded as encapsulating in
>   miniature the characteristic qualities or features of something much
>   larger. "Berlin is a microcosm of Germany, in unity as in division"

[- Google](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=define%20microcosm)

Answer (score 0):

If are referring to people living in a place you may use,

***Residents***:

> - Resident: one who resides in a particular place permanently or for an extended period, (AHD)

- residents are not happy with new traffic rules that will be effective from next June in town.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use ***populace***. According to [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/populace):

> noun (sometimes functioning as plural)
>
> 1) the inhabitants of an area